# SharePoint Add-in web part display options in UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, app-catalog

I've created a SPFx solution where it is not automatically available in all sites. It's been added to App Catalog.

- Enabled - Yes
- Deployed - Yes
- Added to all sites - No

Though it is possible to add the web part via the UI. I'm using Site Scripts to add to site when a workflow provisions the site. However, it is also possible for a Site Owner to add this web part to any site as it's available in the UI.

Is it possible to not display it within the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the web part from the web part toolbox, you can set the `hiddenFromToolbox` property to `true` in the web part manifest:

```
"hiddenFromToolbox": true,
```

**Documentation**: [Hide a web part from the toolbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/hide-web-part-from-toolbox)

Comment: Thanks, the above hides it from the toolbox. Is it possible to not make it available when the user selects 'Add App' or in the Site Contents ? - I only want it to be added programmatically.

Comment: I am not sure if we can remove it from 'Add App' classic experience.